# Removing duplicated columns in a dataframe

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I know this seems like a really simple question and I have scoured google and stackoverflow for it, but could not find exactly what I need.

I have aggregated some data from one dataframe `config` into another `config1` with the following code. The basis of the code was provided by another stackoverflow member Thank You @Sunny Shukla.

```
exprs=map(lambda c: max(c).alias(c), config.columns)
config1=config.groupBy(["seq_id","tool_id"])\
.agg(f.count(f.lit(1)).alias('count'),
     *exprs).where('count = 1').drop('count')
```

The `config` dataframe has 20 columns and the `config1` df has 22 columns because I have grouped it using 2 columns `seq_id` and `tool_id` but mapped the entire original columns to retain the original column names (im sure there is a more elegant way to do this) 
The resulting dataframe `config1` therefore has a duplicated columns of `seq_id` and `tool_id`. If I do 
the `config1.drop('seq_id','tool_id')` then it drops 4 columns and i end up with 18 columns instead of 20.
Is there a more elegant way to do this without writing UDFs?
Thank You

Comment: if you use .select and specify the 20 columns you want, does that work?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do in this query? it appears you are trying to just drop any rows that have a seq_id and tool_id with more than 1 row. In that case why dont you just remove the `, *exprs` from your code and accomplish the same thing?